# DataSet retrieval information not working

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I am trying to write a bit of code that does the following thing:

1. Retrieves data from an Excel file and stores it in a DataTable
2. Fills a DataSet with the DataTable content
3. Uses values from the DataSet and displays them in some text boxes

The problem comes with point no. 3, as the Rows's index is not working and it always shows data  from Row 1 (row 0 is, in fact, counted correctly). I would love to correct it.

Here is the part of the code doing such thing:

```
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & "data source='" & h.FileName & " '; " & "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")


    MyConnection.Open()
    Dim tables As DataTable = MyConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})
    MyConnection.Close()

    hoja = ""
    For i = 0 To tables.Rows.Count - 1
        hoja = tables.Rows(i).Item("Table_Name").ToString
        If hoja.Substring(Len(hoja) - 1, 1) = "$" Then
            i = tables.Rows.Count - 1
        Else
            If hoja.Substring(Len(hoja) - 2, 1) = "$" Then
                i = tables.Rows.Count - 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Select the data from Sheet1 of the workbook.
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & hoja & "]", MyConnection)
    Dim dsds As New System.Data.DataSet
    MyCommand.Fill(dsds)
    MyConnection.Close()
    MyConnection.Dispose()
    MyConnection = Nothing

    rma2.Text = dsds.Tables(0).Rows(1).Item(2)
    Dim valsat As String
    valsat = dsds.Tables(0).Rows(1).Item(8)
    If (dsds.Tables(0).Rows(1).Item(19) Is "-1") Then
        approval.Text = dsds.Tables(0).Rows(1).Item(45)

    End If
    obser.Text = dsds.Tables(0).Rows(2).Item(45)
    model.Text = dsds.Tables(0).Rows(1).Item(16)
    bfme.PerformClick()
    peso.Text = "10"
    bultos.Text = "1"
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. For what i see, you are always accesing row 1 except here `obser.Text = dsds.Tables(0).Rows(2).Item(45)` and the code seems ok. Put a breakpoint after filling the dataset and check the data readed is what you expected.

Comment: It was a problem with the Excel format itself, not with the code run. Could notice it thanks to @Pikoh breakpointing advice